# Windows Update Error 80246002 on 2 newly rebuilt computers

Tags: windows-7, windows-update

I have two machines that I've loaded with Windows 7 SP1 32bit (HP DV9000 and DELL XPS One) in the last 2 days. Both of them eventually got to a point trying to update KB2912390 plus 8 other updates and they all failed with error 80070308.  On the first machine I was able to get the updates by downloading and manually updating KB2912390.  After rebooing the balance  of the updates automatically applied ok.  The second machine I ran the Windows Update fixit on and the updates got applied automatically.  BOTH machines then gave me the 80246002 error when trying to check for updates.  I got the first machine running updates properly by doing an update install of Windows 7 and re-applying the updates.  I'm now stuck at the same place on the second machine and would like to know if anyone has come up with another solution vs. reinstalling SP2?

Comment: See also http://windowsitpro.com/windows-update/tracking-error-80246002-windows-update-problem

Comment: @random this is certainly not too broad, it's very specific to a bad update released today.

Comment: Going with "too broad" based on the asker posting an answer that said they didn't know what happened, but it's gone @chr

Comment: 80246002 = WU_E_DM_INCORRECTFILEHASH (A download manager operation could not be completed because the file digest was not recognized). Make sure no 3rd party AV tools corrupt the downloaded files

Answer (score 1):

Read up on "80246002" As of Tues. (8/26) MS Updates has been down/corrupted due to a bad patch. This deals with the same patch that is causing Windows 8 machines to boot to a black screen.

The quick fix (for the moment) is to change your DNS IP address to 8.8.8.8, then once that is set, try MS updates again. Download the new updates, restart, and then set your DNS address back to automatic (or whatever address you had in there before).

Gotta love Microsoft...

EDIT: Almost forgot, If you have any of these updates on your system, remove them. KB2982791, KB2993651. Thanks.

Comment: It's not the first time windows update can be fixed by changing some network settings, even if it only affects a single machine in a network. Any clue *why*? Sounds a bit like activation/licensing logic gone bad...

Answer (score 0):

Try to [google the error code](https://www.google.nl/search?q=80070308)? Lots of suggestions there, including this one from Microsoft with detailed instructions to solve the problem: http://microsoftlivesupport.com/blog/tag/80070308/

In general with Microsoft error codes: most of the times very usefull information can be obtained from the Microsoft [support site itself](http://microsoftlivesupport.com) or from one of the [Microsoft supported forums](http://answers.microsoft.com).

Ps: Since the answer above is generally applicable I chose to put it as an answer here instead of a comment.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the reply but I Googled and found lots of possible solutions including yours that I tried on the first machine. None of them worked except to run windows 7 update from installation media.

However, after reviewing my question I had a thought and I uninstalled KB2912390, rebooted, and checked for updates.  The check ran normally, found and automatically reinstalled KB2912390 again. After a reboot the check for updates ran normally with no errors and reported that windows was up to date.  Whether it was because I uninstalled this particular KB or not...  All seems to be ok now.

I would like to accept NotAnMSFan's answer but cannot figure out how to do it.  Following his advice I uninstalled the 2 kb's, changed DNS to 8.8.8.8 and was able to get the update process working again.  Thank you

---